# Finding difficulty using clock_nanosleep function to produce a sleep time of 2ms

Tags: c++, posix, clock

Thanks... I’m using the posix precision sleep standard lib function to sleep, but it appears to be returning far too quickly.  Please examine this code and provide details of a way which would repair the function to correctly sleep the correct amount of time.I  need a sleep time of atleast 2ms..

```
void CModbusSlave::sleep(uint32_t seconds, uint32_t useconds)//arguments passed int32_t seconds=0,uint32_t useconds=2000ULL//
{
    int timerResult = 0;
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stopTime);

    uint64_t absTime = (((static_cast<uint64_t>(stopTime.tv_sec) * 1000000000ULL) +
                         (static_cast<uint64_t>(stopTime.tv_nsec))) +
                        ((static_cast<uint64_t>(seconds) * 1000000000ULL) +
                         (static_cast<uint64_t>(useconds)*1000ULL)));
    stopTime.tv_sec = static_cast<uint32_t>(absTime / 1000000000ULL);
    stopTime.tv_nsec = static_cast<uint32_t>(absTime % 1000000000ULL);

    do
    {
        timerResult = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,
                                      TIMER_ABSTIME,
                                      &stopTime,
                                      &stopTime);
        sched_yield();
    }
    while ((timerResult == -1) && (errno == EINTR));
}
```

Comment: The button to format code is the one with the braces: `{}`. You can find more info at the [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: I doubt this is *the* problem, but if I'm reading http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html right, then an interrupted sleep will actually return `EINTR`, rather than returning `-1` and setting `errno` to `EINTR`; so I believe your `while ((timerResult == -1) && (errno == EINTR))` should be `while(timerResult == EINTR)`. Also, have you confirmed that the function is returning `0`? On the off-chance it's returning some error other than `EINTR`, that would really narrow things down.

Comment: Also, it's technically incorrect to make a different system call and then check `errno`: if `sched_yield()` does not encounter an error, then it is allowed to set `errno`.

Comment: Thanks Martinho..I Believe the logic used to sleep the function for 2 ms is correct..but in reality the sleep time measured by me is around 0.600 ms which tells me that function is not returning 0 and that   an interrupt has arrived..ultimately my aim is to get a sleep time of 2ms....is there any other system call to achieve the same without being interrupted